# Magento Order Email Shipping Price

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can i hide the shipping cost from the order emails that have a 0 shipping cost ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide shipping cost, you have to override below file:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml

Your updated code should be like this.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
<?php if ($_code == 'shipping' && $_total->getValue() == 0) continue; ?>
<?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
<?php else:?>
<tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
    <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
    <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif?>
```

Added code snippet:

```
<?php if ($_code == 'shipping' && $_total->getValue() == 0) continue; ?>
```

This code will skip print shipping information if it is zero.

**Note:**
First you can check it by updating code in above file, and then you can override it.